# Match/resize new range based on another sheets selection

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to match the range size of sheet 2 with the selected range in sheet 1?

Comment: Do you really expect an answer to such a vague question? Then, Yes. It's possible. If you want to know how, then you'll need to provide more detail and the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First select *Sheet1* and then select some block of cells.  After running this macro:

```
Sub MatchRange()
    Dim ady As String
    ady = Selection.Address
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range(ady).Select
End Sub
```

you will be on *Sheet2* with the same block selected.