# Select new range based on another sheets selection

Tags: vba, excel

I was assisted with the code below which is great, however it brings through/selects the cell address as per the previous sheet, please can you provide code for a dynamic range so it brings through/selects cells based upon current selection in the new sheet rather than cell address

```
Sub MatchRange()    
    Dim ady As String    
    ady = Selection.Address    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select    
    Range(ady).Select
End Sub
```

Link to where previous code was sourced:
[Match/resize new range based on another sheets selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139292/match-resize-new-range-based-on-another-sheets-selection)

Sorry for being vague, so lets say in sheet a I have range a1:b50 selected, I want to match the selection size in sheet b. So in this situation it would be c51:d100.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want to happen?

Comment: Do you mean you want to select a range in sheet A and get the cell content of sheet B from the same addresses into sheet A?

Comment: what is the correlation between `a1:b50` and `c51:d100`

Comment: Range size, I want to select the same range size in the new sheet as the current sheet

Comment: But _why_ `c51:d100`? like why not `y51:z100` or `g21:h70`

Comment: Sorry can be any as per your comment

Comment: Let me ask this a different way.  Say I select `c51:d100` _on the first sheet_ what should the selection be on the second sheet?

Comment: @chancea I understood him to mean it's whichever cell is currently selected on the second sheet. So, if cell `R35` is selected on the other sheet, he wants that to be the starting point.

Comment: @user3561813 you are just guessing.  I want the OP to explicitly explain that.

Comment: @chancea Any range required at the time that's 50 rows and 2 columns in size

Comment: @Krishn How do I know _what range is required at the time_

Comment: @chancea Ok lets say the same columns and the end of the range in the next sheet

Comment: @user3561813 The OP has spoken.  Keep the columns the same, change the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but I'll give an example on a method of selecting an equivalent sized range based on the selected cells in each sheet. Please try to amend to meet your needs and let us know if you have more specific questions.

```
Sub MatchSelectionArea()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim nRows As Long
    Dim nCols As Long

    Set rng = Selection

    nRows = rng.Rows.Count
    nCols = rng.Columns.Count

    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

    ActiveCell.Resize(nRows, nCols).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: So just to clarify, this is selecting the size based on the current R1C1 selected cell in the second sheet.  Not explained at all in the question

Answer (score 0):

When your code reads the `Selection.Address` you should prefix it with the sheet that you want to use for the source. So:

```
Sub MatchRange()    
    Dim ady As String    
    ady = Sheets("sheet_name").Selection.Address    
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select    
    Range(ady).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I should prob ask why you need this? A lot of actions (copy & paste, etc) do not need to have the destination selection set to the same size.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you need but this is an example to get a range of the same dimensions of another range (hope it helps)

```
Set ady = Range("A1:C3")
RngNumCol = ady.Columns.Count
RngNumRow = ady.Rows.Count

NewRngStart = ActiveCell.Address 'Here the starting cell of the new range
NewRngEnd = Range(NewRngStart).Offset(RngNumRow - 1, RngNumCol - 1).Address
Set NewRng = Range(NewRngStart, NewRngEnd)

'Test
For Each mycell In NewRng.Cells
    mycell .Value = "Test"
Next
```